# Why does NSHTTPURLResponse return nil? NSURLSession, Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to write a function fetches JSON from a service on the web but one of the lines (commented) keeps returning nil and I have no idea why. Any help is appreciated! :) Thanks!!

```
func parseJSON(long: CLLocationDegrees, lat: CLLocationDegrees) {

    var longitude : String = "\(long)"
    var latitude : String =  "\(lat)"

    longitude = longitude.substringToIndex(longitude.characters.indexOf(".")!)
    latitude = latitude.substringToIndex(latitude.characters.indexOf(".")!)

    print("\(latitude),\(longitude)")

    let appId = "xyz" //Insert API Key
    let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&units=metric&appid=\(appId)"

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        //Keeps returning nil. No idea why.
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

            print("Success!")
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")
            } else {
                print("STATUSCODE=\(statusCode)")
            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: NSURLResponse instead of NSHTTPURLResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func dataTaskWithRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest,
       completionHandler completionHandler: (NSData?,
                                  NSURLResponse?,
                                  NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

The initial method takes an `NSURLResponse`. This is the response of the requested URL. `NSURLResponse` can be of any kind of response.

`NSHTTPURLResponse` is a subclass of `NSURLResponse`, you can cast your response to `NSHTTPURLResponse` only if you are sure that your webservice encode responses using the HTTP protocol. Otherwise, the cast will always return `nil`.

Also, I'm seeing that the Webservice that you are using has some restrictions of usage :

> How to get accurate API response
>
> 1 Do not send requests more then 1 time per 10 minutes from one device/one API key. Normally the weather is not changing so
> frequently.
>
> 2 Use the name of the server as api.openweathermap.org. Please never
> use the IP address of the server.
>
> 3 Call API by city ID instead of city name, city coordinates or zip
> code. In this case you get precise respond exactly for your city.
>
> **4 Free account has limitation of capacity and data availability. If
> you do not get respond from server do not try to repeat your
> request immediately, but only after 10 min. Also we recommend to store
> your previous request data.**

Now I'm thinking that your problem could come from there.